# Hosting on Heroku not working (error setting certificate verify locations)

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm in an online course, and I am currently learning to host a web app on Heroku. I haven't really learned Git yet (it's in the next module), but I'm following everything the instructor is doing, but I've encountered an issue. I did `git push heroku master`, but I'm now getting an error.

[image: The error I'm getting]

I also did `git remote -v` and got this:

[image: What I got]

I've searched this up on Google and tried to find a solution for the past 2 hours, but I can't find anything. If there's anything (screenshot, etc.) that's needed I'll be happy to add that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what `git config --show-scope --show-origin http.sslcainfo` returns (using [Git for Windows 2.27 or 2.28](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

Make sure the path `C:\xxx\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt` does exist, or adjust your Git installation path.

Comment: I changed the `C:\xxx\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt` path to the correct one and now its working. Thank you so much for the help!